# Upvote distribution SEDE query

Tags: sql, stackexchange

There is a 1-to-many relationship between the `posts` table and the `votes` table, and they join on `posts.id = votes.postid`. I would like to know how many posts have 1, 2, 3, 5, etc. votes.

Thanks to Waffles' [most controversial posts query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/87/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site), it was trivial to write [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/s/1836/answer-upvote-distribution):

```
declare @VoteStats table (PostId int, up int) 

set nocount on

insert @VoteStats
select
    PostId, 
    up = sum(case when VoteTypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
from Votes
where VoteTypeId in (2,3)
group by PostId

set nocount off

select up, count(*)
from @VoteStats
group by up;
```

However, [it runs in a full 22 seconds](http://data.stackexchange.com/mini-profiler-results?id=fb123312-b40c-43cd-a52c-953d85b358c7) on the Stack Overflow data dump.

Am I overlooking an obvious way to speed this query up, perhaps avoiding the creation of  the VoteStats table?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't restrict your where clause to `where VoteTypeId = 2` and then just `count(*)` the rows?  That's essentially what you're currently asking.  Or do you also have a `down` column that goes the other way?

Comment: @X-Zero That [only shoved off one second](http://data.stackexchange.com/mini-profiler-results?id=ee272d21-702b-45ca-bb19-ab3d2f17a403), but makes a lot of sense. Plus, it removed a subtle problem with showing a count of posts with "0 votes" (they actually aren't all posts with no votes). I should've totally seen that

Comment: Then that's probably as fast as it's going to get...

Answer (score 2):

Not creating the VoteStats table makes a big difference. Gets it down to ~5.5 seconds.

```
set nocount on

select up, count(*)
from (
    select
        PostId,
        up = sum(case when VoteTypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
    from Votes
    where VoteTypeId in (2,3)
    group by PostId
) a
group by up
order by up
```

http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112108/

From the execution plan of the table variable version, it looks like the table scan and the sort on it is pretty expensive.

Comment: ...and combining this with the other answer cuts the time down to 2 seconds. Pesky syntax! :D

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be faster, because instead of summing up 1 for every vote that has a VoteTypeId=2, I counted votes with VoteTypeId=2:

```
with VoteCountsByPost as
(
    select 
        p.Id as PostId,
        count(v.Id) as up
    from Posts p
    left join Votes v on v.PostId = p.Id and v.VoteTypeId = 2
    group by p.Id
)
select up, count(*) 
from VoteCountsByPost
group by up
order by up
```

Also, please note that the results are a little different: you query does not take into account posts that have no votes.

For instance, if a post has a vote with VoteTypeId != 2, then that post will appear with 0 ups. If it has no votes whatsoever, then that post will be completely excluded from the result set.

I don't know if this is the intended behavior.

Comment: Yeah, this is what X-Zero suggested. See the comments on the question for my follow up. :)